# Cannot display values from NgRx Store with Selectors and AsyncPipe

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have implemented a simple application with NgRx store and am having trouble displaying data from Store with AsyncPipe. In the console I got an error:

*Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.*

My code from component:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProductListState } from 'src/app/models/state';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { loadProductList } from '../../actions/products.actions';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private store: Store<ProductListState>) { }

   products$: Observable<Product[]> = this.store.select(state => state.products);
   isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(state => state.isLoading);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(loadProductList());
  }
}
```

And in the template I want to display it as below using AsyncPipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products$ | async; let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{product.id}}</th>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

I assume that NgRx and dispatching actions works good because in Store DevTools I can see the received data:

[State after load product list - DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8alc.png)

[Error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMMto.png)

Comment: can you add `{{ products$ | async | json }}` before your <tr>? is it array? I suspect you need to select `state.products.products` according to the screenshot

Comment: You are right, I had a problem in interface of the state. Now I do select `state.products.products`. I need to figure out where I made this nested array, but still it is working. Thanks a lot :)